# How to make a dynamic layout with clickable text, checkboxes and buttons?

Tags: android, dynamic, layout, button, clickable

Give me please an advise, I want to make a dynamic layout which contains mixed elements
[text] [checkbox] [button]
[text] [checkbox] [button]
[text] [checkbox] [button]
......

Can you give me some sample code, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final TableLayout Tlayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());  
Trow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext()); 

checkBox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
Trow.addView(checkBox);

button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
button.setText("Button");
Trow.addView(button);

textBox = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
textBox.setText("default_value");
Trow.addView(textBox);

Tlayout.addView(Trow);
```

This code may help you to create dynamic form elements.